# Trying to create an SQLite table in Python 3 but it's saying I'm supplying too many values

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I want to create a simple database that has a list of names and ID numbers. I want there to be 2 columns and a total of 4 rows - one for each person. The error I keep getting is:

> OperationalError: table contacts has 2 columns but 4 values were
>   supplied

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test2.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (name text, id_num text)''')

list = [('Taylor', '001'), ('Tory', '002'), ('Joe', '003'), ('Steve', '004')]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO contacts VALUES (?,?,?,?)", list)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You need a placeholder (?) per column, not per value set.

...values(?,?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have two values per row in your list so you need to tell the INSERT INTO statement to expect only two values rather than four:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO contacts VALUES (?,?)", list)
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Thanks! Any suggestions on how to make it so my code doesn't keep adding to the database every time I run it? Some sort of "if the table exists, don't run this code" function?

Comment: Sorry not that good with python.  I would do a query to find out what's in the table already and then use an IF statement or maybe CASE to insert the values that aren't already there.

Comment: @samort7 : if you have a unique column (`id_num` looks like it should be unique) you could use `INSERT OR IGNORE ...` to insert only those values that are not already in the table. To make this work you need to change the `CREATE TABLE` statement to add a UNIQUE constraint to one (or both) of the columns.

Comment: Cool! Thank you mhawke and Darvanen. I'll try that out!